# Batch Scripting: open the printingtool Windows

Tags: windows, batch-file, printing

I need your help :D

We´re using 3 different printers, and so we open these printingtool windows, where you can see all the printing jobs are in qeue, abort them and/or hold on the printer.
Is there any chance to write a skript or something to open all of these 3 Windows with just one click?

I hope you can help me a out, thanks a lot!
-Alex

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use rundll32 and printUI :
example for printer named PDFCreator :

```
rundll32 printui, PrintUIEntry /o  /nPDFCreator
```

You can have more control over printers, try :

```
printui /?
```

beware printui commands are **case-sensitive**